# How to manage a SMTP server in a Java EE application?

Tags: jakarta-ee, smtp, postfix-mta

I am building a Java EE web application that has to be able to connect to a Postfix server and "manage" it (change informations in his configuration file....).

I had found a lot of documents that shows how to create a new smtp server but I didn't found anything about how to manage a one that I had installed on my VMWare.
So if anyone can point me in the right direction and explain what could I use for this,that would be great.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access a linux file using java program on windows machine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10016140/how-to-access-a-linux-file-using-java-program-on-windows-machine)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Postfix, but looking at [Postfix Basic Configuration](http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html) it seems like it is controlled via simple [`main.cf` file](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html). So all you have to do is to create a web GUI reading and modifying that file.

After modifying the file it seems like you need to reload Postfix:

```
# /etc/init.d/postfix reload
```

Java is capable of running any system processes/scripts.

## Problems

- your application will probably need root privileges to modify Postfix configuration file and reload the service
- the application needs to run on the same virtual machine as Postfix to have access to `main.cf` file. Otherwise some sort of network file system or synchronization is required. Alternatively - load the file locally and have some external script synchronizing it.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't realy understood how I can access to this file to manage the smtp server, there is an API that could help me or any other method ?? ( for exemple to manage LDAP server, we can use JNDI or SringLDAP )

Comment: @InessBha: as I said, I don't know Postfix. Quick googling only shows this file. So this means you have to physically open the file on Postfix servers' file-system and modify it.

Comment: I don't knouw yet how to manage this server but thanks Tomasz for all this information